# How to use datanucleus's enhances within maven in eclipse kepler?

Tags: maven-3, jdo, datanucleus, eclipse-kepler

Obviously [the documentations](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_0/jdo/maven.html) are outdated and even having mistakes.

This is my POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>mg.labs.jdo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdo-enhancement</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>jdo-enhancement</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-accessplatform-jdo-rdbms</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0-release</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>datanucleus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0-release</version>
                <configuration>
                    <api>JDO</api>
                    <props>${basedir}/datanucleus.properties</props>
                    <log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

1. The api and enhancer versions stated in the docs for for an old version. How can I use `3.3.8` or `4.0.0.M2` instead ? Simply changing the numbers didn't work !
2. Eclipse is showing the following error `Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.datanucleus:datanucleus-maven-plugin:3.3.0-release:enhance (execution: default, phase: process-classes)`
3. Running the goals `install` shows the following error:

   Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/3.2.5/datanucleus-core-3.2.5.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/4.0.0-m2/datanucleus-core-4.0.0-m2.jar."

Although I haven't included versions `3.2.5` nor `4.0.0-m2`. I wish I could be using the latest version but I don't know how, as I said, changing the version numbers doesn't work as expected.

My main goal is to run package and enhance the classes before packaging, which is just what the documentation tries to do. **How to do that with the latest datanculeus release version ?**

**EDIT**
I debugged as Neil adviced, there is what I think is significant:
(At the beginning, these lines indicate the dependencies for the included maven dependency)

```
[DEBUG] mg.labs.jdo:jdo-enhancement:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]    org.datanucleus:datanucleus-accessplatform-jdo-rdbms:pom:3.3.0-release:compile
[DEBUG]       javax.jdo:jdo-api:jar:3.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]          javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:jar:3.2.5:compile
[DEBUG]       org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jdo:jar:3.2.4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.datanucleus:datanucleus-jdo-query:jar:3.0.2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.datanucleus:datanucleus-rdbms:jar:3.2.4:compile
[DEBUG]    junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
```

(These lines at the starts are the ones indicating some unexpected events for datanucleus plugin, such as not being able to download meta-data xml files and including `datanucleus-core 4.0.0-m3` files, the successive lines are just a result of that faulty inclusion)

```
[INFO] --- datanucleus-maven-plugin:3.3.0-release:enhance (default) @ jdo-enhancement ---
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core/maven-metadata.xml in local (/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/maven-metadata.xml
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core/maven-metadata.xml in DN_M2_Repo (http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core/maven-metadata.xml in sonatype-nexus-snapshots (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots)
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=0, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=41, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=1, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=18, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=1, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=40, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=6063, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=2}
[DEBUG] org.datanucleus:datanucleus-maven-plugin:jar:3.3.0-release:
[DEBUG]    org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:jar:4.0.0-m3:runtime
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.8:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:2.3.0:compile
[DEBUG]          org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile
[DEBUG]          org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:2.3.0:compile
[DEBUG]             org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:no_aop:3.1.0:compile
[DEBUG]                org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guava:jar:0.9.9:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.5.5:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.xbean:xbean-reflect:jar:3.4:compile
[DEBUG]          log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.12:compile
[DEBUG]          commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]       junit:junit:jar:3.8.2:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.datanucleus:datanucleus-maven-plugin:3.3.0-release
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.datanucleus:datanucleus-maven-plugin:3.3.0-release
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.datanucleus:datanucleus-maven-plugin:3.3.0-release
[DEBUG]   Included: org.datanucleus:datanucleus-maven-plugin:jar:3.3.0-release
[DEBUG]   Included: org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:jar:4.0.0-m3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.8
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:2.3.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:no_aop:3.1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guava:jar:0.9.9
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.xbean:xbean-reflect:jar:3.4
[DEBUG]   Included: log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.12
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: junit:junit:jar:3.8.2
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0.4
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0.4
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0.4
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:2.3.0
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.5.5
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.2
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.datanucleus:datanucleus-maven-plugin:3.3.0-release:enhance from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.datanucleus:datanucleus-maven-plugin:3.3.0-release, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@591ce4fe]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-maven-plugin:3.3.0-release:enhance' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) alwaysDetachable = false
[DEBUG]   (f) api = JDO
[DEBUG]   (f) classpathElements = [/home/mgelbana/workspace/kepler_maven_by_example/jdo-enhancement/target/classes, /home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/javax/jdo/jdo-api/3.0.1/jdo-api-3.0.1.jar, /home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.jar, /home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/3.2.5/datanucleus-core-3.2.5.jar, /home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-api-jdo/3.2.4/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.4.jar, /home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-jdo-query/3.0.2/datanucleus-jdo-query-3.0.2.jar, /home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-rdbms/3.2.4/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.4.jar]
[DEBUG]   (f) detachListener = false
[DEBUG]   (f) fork = true
[DEBUG]   (f) generateConstructor = true
[DEBUG]   (f) generatePK = true
[DEBUG]   (f) log4jConfiguration = /home/mgelbana/workspace/kepler_maven_by_example/jdo-enhancement/log4j.properties
[DEBUG]   (f) metadataDirectory = /home/mgelbana/workspace/kepler_maven_by_example/jdo-enhancement/target/classes
[DEBUG]   (f) metadataIncludes = **/*.jdo, **/*.class
[DEBUG]   (f) pluginArtifacts = [org.datanucleus:datanucleus-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:3.3.0-release:, org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:jar:4.0.0-m3:runtime, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.8:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile, org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:2.3.0:compile, org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:no_aop:3.1.0:compile, org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guava:jar:0.9.9:compile, org.apache.xbean:xbean-reflect:jar:3.4:compile, log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.12:compile, commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile, com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0:compile, junit:junit:jar:3.8.2:compile]
[DEBUG]   (f) quiet = false
[DEBUG]   (f) verbose = true
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Metadata Directory is : /home/mgelbana/workspace/kepler_maven_by_example/jdo-enhancement/target/classes
[DEBUG] Executing command line:
[DEBUG] /bin/sh -c java -cp /home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-maven-plugin/3.3.0-release/datanucleus-maven-plugin-3.3.0-release.jar:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/4.0.0-m3/datanucleus-core-4.0.0-m3.jar:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.8/plexus-utils-3.0.8.jar:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-bean/2.3.0/sisu-inject-bean-2.3.0.jar:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/3.1.0/sisu-guice-3.1.0-no_aop.jar:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guava/0.9.9/sisu-guava-0.9.9.jar:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/apache/xbean/xbean-reflect/3.4/xbean-reflect-3.4.jar:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.jar:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.1/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.2/junit-3.8.2.jar:/home/mgelbana/workspace/kepler_maven_by_example/jdo-enhancement/target/classes:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/javax/jdo/jdo-api/3.0.1/jdo-api-3.0.1.jar:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.jar:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/3.2.5/datanucleus-core-3.2.5.jar:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-api-jdo/3.2.4/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.4.jar:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-jdo-query/3.0.2/datanucleus-jdo-query-3.0.2.jar:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-rdbms/3.2.4/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.4.jar -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/mgelbana/workspace/kepler_maven_by_example/jdo-enhancement/log4j.properties org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer -v -api JDO /home/mgelbana/workspace/kepler_maven_by_example/jdo-enhancement/target/classes/mg/labs/jdo/enhancement/App.class /home/mgelbana/workspace/kepler_maven_by_example/jdo-enhancement/target/classes/mg/labs/jdo/enhancement/QApp.class
[DEBUG] Exit code: 1
[DEBUG] --------------------
[DEBUG]  Standard output from the DataNucleus tool org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer :
[DEBUG] --------------------
[INFO] 
[DEBUG] --------------------
[ERROR] --------------------
[ERROR]  Standard error from the DataNucleus tool + org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer :
[ERROR] --------------------
[ERROR] Exception in thread "main" Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/3.2.5/datanucleus-core-3.2.5.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/4.0.0-m3/datanucleus-core-4.0.0-m3.jar."
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/3.2.5/datanucleus-core-3.2.5.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/4.0.0-m3/datanucleus-core-4.0.0-m3.jar."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i simply changed all versions to the latest **4.0.0-m2** when I wanted to use it. Can't get simpler.

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
   <artifactId>datanucleus-accessplatform-jdo-rdbms</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.0-m2-release</version>
   <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>, works for you ? It doesn't work for me. Should I configure a specific repository ?

Comment: Why would 4.0.0-m2-release be expected to work for anyone? There is no such release. Anyone can look at Maven Central and see that the latest release is "4.0.0-m2". Also you have two versions in your POM, and I said change all versions to the latest.

Comment: Ok I changed all versions to `3.3.8` and the dependency and the plugin as found in maven repository but I still get the same maven error: `Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.datanucleus:datanucleus-maven-plugin:3.3.8:enhance (execution: default, phase: process-classes)`

Comment: Eclipse m2e plugin doesn't support 3rd party plugins execution. Those plugins are executed yourself. This is the Eclipse m2e plugin, nothing to do with DataNucleus. You say you use some old version of DataNucleus, but then that will never be executable by Eclipse m2e either.

Comment: I ran `mvn clean install` from the command line and I got the following error message: `Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/3.2.5/datanucleus-core-3.2.5.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/4.0.0-m3/datanucleus-core-4.0.0-m3.jar."`. The plugin & the dependency are using different versions.

Comment: So you either have 3.2.5 in your POM directly or you have an OLD version of the Maven plugin. That's all there is. You can easily run mvn --debug to DEBUG your maven problems.

Comment: I deleted `/home/mgelbana/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus` and ran `mvn clean install` but I still get the same error. Would you please post your pom that uses datanucleus's maven plugin to enhance the classes before packaging them ?

Comment: see my comment above. Your POM is the problem. mvn --debug tells you where anything comes from. My POM is exactly the same as the DataNucleus documentation.

Comment: I `--debug`ed and I think there missing meta-data files on `datanucleus.com` but I'm not sure if this is the problem.

Comment: really no idea what "datanucleus.com" has to do with anything. Nothing is present on "datanucleus.com". JARs are in Maven Central. XSD/DTD are on Oracle.

Comment: `[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core/maven-metadata.xml in DN_M2_Repo (http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core/maven-metadata.xml in sonatype-nexus-snapshots (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots)`. I meant `datanucleus.org`. Would you please post your `--debug` trace so I compare it to mine ?

Comment: Why don't you just download the tutorial that DataNucleus provides and run it using Maven? The latest version seems to be labelled 4.0 (using 4.0.0-m1). Works for me also

Comment: Thanks a lot. The POM in the samples worked even from within Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Neil's suggestion to check [datanucleus's samples](http://sourceforge.net/projects/datanucleus/files/datanucleus-samples/), here is a functioning POM file with JDO enhancer configured:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-samples-jdo-tutorial</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>4.0</version>
    <name>DataNucleus AccessPlatform Tutorial for JDO</name>
    <url>http://www.datanucleus.org</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>DN_M2_Repo</id>
            <name>DataNucleus Repository</name>
            <url>http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>DataNucleus_2</id>
            <url>http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
            <version>[4.0.0-m1, )</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
            <version>[4.0.0-m1, )</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
            <version>[3.0, )</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>[1.2, 1.3)</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ENABLE THIS FOR H2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
            <version>[4.0.0-m1, )</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.168</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ENABLE THIS FOR HSQLDB -->
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
            <version>[4.0.0-m1, )</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0.4</version>
        </dependency-->

        <!-- ENABLE THIS FOR MYSQL -->
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
            <version>[4.0.0-m1, )</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.17</version>
        </dependency-->

        <!-- ENABLE THIS FOR ODF -->
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-odf</artifactId>
            <version>[4.0.0-m1, )</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.odftoolkit</groupId>
            <artifactId>odfdom-java</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>[2.8, 3.0)</version>
        </dependency-->

        <!-- ENABLE THIS FOR EXCEL -->
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-excel</artifactId>
            <version>[4.0.0-m1, )</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency-->

        <!-- ENABLE THIS FOR MongoDB -->
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>[4.0.0-m1, )</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>[2.5, 3.0)</version>
        </dependency-->

        <!-- ENABLE THIS FOR HBase -->
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-hbase</artifactId>
            <version>[4.0.0-m1, )</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
            <version>0.94.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
            <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.3</version>
        </dependency-->

        <!-- ENABLE THIS FOR Neo4j -->
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>[4.0.0-m1, )</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency-->

        <!-- ENABLE THIS FOR Cassandra -->
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-cassandra</artifactId>
            <version>[4.0.0-m1, )</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-rc2</version>
        </dependency-->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.jdo</include>
                    <include>**/*.orm</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*.log</include>
                                <include>tutorial.ods</include>
                                <include>tutorial.xls</include>
                                <include>testDB</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <!--configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration-->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>datanucleus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0-m1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <api>JDO</api>
                    <persistenceUnitName>Tutorial</persistenceUnitName>
                    <log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.Main</mainClass>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <key>log4j.configuration</key>
                            <value>file:${basedir}/log4j.properties</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>${basedir}/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```